# Google direction route from current location to known location

Tags: android, json, routes, maps, google-directions-api

I use the `MapsActivity` class in this project. On my map you can see many markers. I have many known locations, but in my code I just display two locations for example.

I don't understand how to use the direction API and JSON. How can I display the route, distance, and travelling time from my current location (changing) to a known location (constant)?

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
    private Map<Marker, Class<?>> allMarkersMap = new HashMap<Marker, Class<?>>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        Marker marker1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(14.608177, 120.967422))
                .title("Sample2")
                .snippet("zzzzzzz"));
        allMarkersMap.put(marker1, MainActivity.class);

        Marker marker2 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(14.611335, 120.962160))
                .title("Sample1")
                .snippet("sssssss"));
        allMarkersMap.put(marker2, MainActivity2Activity.class);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                Class<?> cls = allMarkersMap.get(marker);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, cls);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have a look at this tutorial:

[Drawing driving route directions between two locations using Google Directions in Google Map Android API V2](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android-api-v2/)

It shows how to draw a route map between two points, calculate distance and travel time.

If you are having problems in following the tutorial, download the Android Studio sample project from the link below:

[MapDemo.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tqwc62cn4dcr7wh/MapDemo.zip?dl=0)

```
public class DirectionsJSONParser {

    /** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list of lists containing latitude and longitude */
    public List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String,String>>>() ;
        JSONArray jRoutes = null;
        JSONArray jLegs = null;
        JSONArray jSteps = null;

        try {

            jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

            /** Traversing all routes */
            for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){
                jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
                List path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                /** Traversing all legs */
                for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){
                    jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                    /** Traversing all steps */
                    for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
                        String polyline = "";
                        polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                        List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                        /** Traversing all points */
                        for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
                            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).latitude) );
                            hm.put("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).longitude) );
                            path.add(hm);
                        }
                    }
                routes.add(path);
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e){
    }

    return routes;
    }
    /**
    * Method to decode polyline points
    * Courtesy : http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java
    * */
    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }
}
MainActivity.Java

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

GoogleMap map;
ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;
TextView tvDistanceDuration;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvDistanceDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_distance_time);

    // Initializing
    markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
    map = fm.getMap();

    // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Setting onclick event listener for the map
    map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

            // Already two locations
            if (markerPoints.size() > 1) {
                markerPoints.clear();
                map.clear();
            }

            // Adding new item to the ArrayList
            markerPoints.add(point);

            // Creating MarkerOptions
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

            // Setting the position of the marker
            options.position(point);

            /**
             * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
             * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.
             */
            if (markerPoints.size() == 1) {
                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
            } else if (markerPoints.size() == 2) {
                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
            }

            // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
            map.addMarker(options);

            // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
            if (markerPoints.size() >= 2) {
                LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(0);
                LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(1);

                // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

                DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                downloadTask.execute(url);
            }
        }
    });
}

private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {

    // Origin of route
    String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;

    // Destination of route
    String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;

    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;

    return url;
}

/**
 * A method to download json data from url
 */
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        br.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    } finally {
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}

// Fetches data from url passed
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    // Downloading data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        try {
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
    // doInBackground()
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }
}

/**
 * A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format
 */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        String distance = "";
        String duration = "";

        if (result.size() < 1) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Points", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        // Traversing through all the routes
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                if (j == 0) {    // Get distance from the list
                    distance = (String) point.get("distance");
                    continue;
                } else if (j == 1) { // Get duration from the list
                    duration = (String) point.get("duration");
                    continue;
                }

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(2);
            lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
        }

        tvDistanceDuration.setText("Distance:" + distance + ", Duration:" + duration);

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        map.addPolyline(lineOptions);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using android studio. I'm getting some errors while trying that code, I think its because we have diff. platforms :( Help me, our deadline is getting near :'((((

Comment: @Newbee sorry for late replay.I have attached another link in my answer where i have attached android studio sample project for draw route map b/w two points.Plese have look mark this answer as correct if it helped you.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Im going to check the attached zip file in android studio. Im going to comment again here for help. Please always reply to help me. Thanks

Comment: Error: Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project please help me with this :( Im always getting this problem.

Comment: What version of android stuido you are using?

Comment: @Newbee please update it to 1.3.2 and run project again

Comment: thanks! it's working now. But I have another problem because I have many destinations that are already set. I dont know how to code the string of my markers latlng

Answer (score 4):

The code is for drawing the distance between any two points, start is the current location and the other is a location stored in the SQLite db.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback ,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
ArrayList<LatLng> MarkerPoints;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
String lat, lon;
LatLng start;
LatLng dest;
String destlat;
String destlon;

public void setLat(String lat) {
    this.lat = lat;
}

public void setLon(String lon) {
    this.lon = lon;
}

public void setDestlat(String destlat) {
    this.destlat = destlat;
}

public void setDestlon(String destlon) {
    this.destlon = destlon;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }
    // Initializing
    MarkerPoints = new ArrayList<>();

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    Log.d("OnmapREady fired", "fired");

    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }


}

public void mapOperations(){

    Log.d("Map operations called","Hope");

    LatLng point = start;

    // Already two locations
    if (MarkerPoints.size() > 1) {
        MarkerPoints.clear();
        mMap.clear();
    }

    // Adding new item to the ArrayList
    MarkerPoints.add(start);

    // adding destination from database
    LocationsDB db = new LocationsDB(MapsActivity.this);
    String loc = db.getTermValues();
    Log.d("location from db",loc);
    String[] separated = loc.split(" ");



    //try {
    Double lt = Double.parseDouble(separated[0]);
    Double ln = Double.parseDouble(separated[1]);
    dest = new LatLng(lt,ln);



    MarkerPoints.add(dest);
    //}
    //catch(Exception e) {
    //   Log.d("Wrong target location", e.toString());
    //}


    // Creating MarkerOptions
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

    // Setting the position of the marker
    options.position(start);
    options.position(dest);

    /**
     * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
     * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.
     */
    if (MarkerPoints.size() == 1) {
        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
    } else if (MarkerPoints.size() == 2) {
        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
    }


    // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
    mMap.addMarker(options);

    // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
    if (MarkerPoints.size() >= 2) {
        LatLng origin = MarkerPoints.get(0);
        LatLng dest = MarkerPoints.get(1);

        // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
        String url = getUrl(origin, dest);
        Log.d("onMapClick", url.toString());
        FetchUrl FetchUrl = new FetchUrl();

        // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
        FetchUrl.execute(url);
        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(origin));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
    }


}


private String getUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {

    // Origin of route
    String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;

    // Destination of route
    String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;


    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;


    return url;
}

/**
 * A method to download json data from url
 */
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();
        Log.d("downloadUrl", data.toString());
        br.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
    } finally {
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}

// Fetches data from url passed
private class FetchUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        try {
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            Log.d("Background Task data", data.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
        parserTask.execute(result);

    }
}

/**
 * A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format
 */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            Log.d("ParserTask",jsonData[0].toString());
            DataParser parser = new DataParser();
            Log.d("ParserTask", parser.toString());

            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            Log.d("ParserTask","Executing routes");
            Log.d("ParserTask",routes.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ParserTask",e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;

        // Traversing through all the routes
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            points = new ArrayList<>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(10);
            lineOptions.color(Color.RED);

            Log.d("onPostExecute","onPostExecute lineoptions decoded");

        }

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        if(lineOptions != null) {
            mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
        }
        else {
            Log.d("onPostExecute","without Polylines drawn");
        }
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    Log.d("OnConnected fired","fired");

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        lat = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
        lon = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude());

        start = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(),mLastLocation.getLongitude());


        Toast.makeText(this,"Connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mapOperations();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    //move map camera
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

    //stop location updates
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Asking user if explanation is needed
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted. Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {

                // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other permissions this app might request.
        // You can add here other case statements according to your requirement.
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    }
```

}

This is the code for finding and drawing the routes between the points.

```
 public class DataParser {
/** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list of lists containing latitude and longitude */
public List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

    List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<>() ;
    JSONArray jRoutes;
    JSONArray jLegs;
    JSONArray jSteps;

    try {

        jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

        /** Traversing all routes */
        for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){
            jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
            List path = new ArrayList<>();

            /** Traversing all legs */
            for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){
                jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                /** Traversing all steps */
                for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
                    String polyline = "";
                    polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                    List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                    /** Traversing all points */
                    for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
                        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
                        hm.put("lat", Double.toString((list.get(l)).latitude) );
                        hm.put("lng", Double.toString((list.get(l)).longitude) );
                        path.add(hm);
                    }
                }
                routes.add(path);
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e){
    }


    return routes;
}


/**
 * Method to decode polyline points
 * Courtesy : http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java
 * */
private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

    List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        poly.add(p);
    }

    return poly;
}
```

}